# Given the points $A(2,5,-1), B(-2,1,4), \text{ and } C(0,-6,4)$, find a point $P$ such that $\vec{AP}=-5 \vec{BP}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know I can find point $P$ by just finding the coordinates of $\vec{AP}$ and $-5 \vec{BP}$ and then set the corresponding coordinates equal to each other.

But I was wondering if I can use the fact that if point $P(x,y,z)$ is on the line that passes through points $A(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, then there exist numbers $s$ and $t$ such that $s+t=1$ and

$$
x=sx_1+tx_2\\
y=sy_1+ty_2\\
z=sz_1+tz_2
$$

So for $\vec{AP}=-5 \vec{BP}$, $t=-5$ and $s=6$, but what would be my $x_1$ and $x_2$ be for instance? This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Did you omit some info relating A,B to the point C in your question? You give C's coordinates but it is not mentioned in your question at all.

Comment: @coffeemath no I didn't omit anything about $C$. It's used in a different part to the question.

Comment: Ok you can use that P is on the line through A and B. Suggest you parametrize that line and then let P be on it and *between* A and B, and located in a ratio to satisfy |AP|=5|BP| where by abs val I mean just the usual length (always positive). The negative sign will then hold as P is between A and B.